# Could not connect websocket using Action Cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, websocket, actioncable

Could not connect websocket using Action Cable in Rails 5.1. HTTP server is Unicorn on nginx and adapter is Redis.

Rails configuration is the following.

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
```

nginx configuration is the following.

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/rails/current/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  charset utf-8;
  server_name sub.example.com;
  root /rails/current/public;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://unicorn;
      break;
    }
  }
  location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
  ...
}
```

Errors in console of web browser are the following.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://sub.example.com/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Errors in Rails are the following.

```
[ERROR] Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: close, HTTP_UPGRADE: )
[INFO] Finished "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2017-xx-xx
```

**A strangest thing is a error in Rails does not have `HTTP_UPGRADE` value**. But HTTP request headers of web browser include `Upgrade` key and `websocket` value. Also setting `"websocket"` for proxy header in nginx configurations.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> On the back of that writeup, I just realized the universal solution is
>   a simple change to the config/secrets.yml file to reference the
>   ENV["PORT"] setting
>   ...

`# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.`

> ```
> development:
>   secret_key_base: 231bf79489c63f8c8facd7...
>   action_cable_url : http://localhost:<%= ENV["PORT"] %>
>
> test:
>   secret_key_base: 1ab8adbcf8410aebb...
>   action_cable_url : http://localhost:<%= ENV["PORT"] %>
>
> # Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
> # instead read values from the environment.
> production:
>   secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
>   action_cable_url : <%= ENV["SERVER_PORT"] %>
> ```

.

> You can also have this in your dot file:
>
> export PORT=3000

[source](https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial/issues/357)